# TinyDB - SharedPreferences - getting: Forgot to register a type adapter?

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, tinydb

I just discovered [TinyDB](https://github.com/kcochibili/TinyDB--Android-Shared-Preferences-Turbo) which seems quite useful to handle object storage into the SharedPreferences.

I'm almost there but I'm getting an error: **Forgot to register a type adapter?** 
Note that the GSON library from Google is used together with TinyDB.

So, let me share my code with you. Any help would be highly appreciated.

**Here is the stackTrace**

```
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Attempted to serialize
java.lang.Class: com.ilepez.weatherapp.data.model.CityArrayList. Forgot to register a type adapter?
at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapters$1.write(TypeAdapters.java:76)
at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapters$1.write(TypeAdapters.java:69)
at com.google.gson.Gson.toJson(Gson.java:669)
at com.google.gson.Gson.toJson(Gson.java:648)
at com.google.gson.Gson.toJson(Gson.java:603)
at com.google.gson.Gson.toJson(Gson.java:583)
at com.ilepez.weatherapp.utils.TinyDB.putObject(TinyDB.java:462)
at com.ilepez.weatherapp.activity.SearchActivity.onItemClick(SearchActivity.java:67)
at android.widget.AutoCompleteTextView.performCompletion(AutoCompleteTextView.java:928)
at android.widget.AutoCompleteTextView.access$500(AutoCompleteTextView.java:93)
at android.widget.AutoCompleteTextView$DropDownItemClickListener.onItemClick(AutoCompleteTextView.java:1230)
at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:345)
at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1547)
at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:3821)
at android.widget.AbsListView$3.run(AbsListView.java:5841)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7229)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
    07-17 10:55:26.283 15392-15392/com.ilepez.weatherapp E/libEGL: call to OpenGL ES API with no current context (logged once per thread)
```

So, let me share my code with you. Any help would be highly appreciated.

**So here is the moment when I add my object to TinyDB**

```
City city = new City(description, itemLatitude, itemLongitude);
                ArrayList<Object> savedCity = new ArrayList<>();
                savedCity.add(city);
for (City oCity : CityArrayList.getInstance().getCityList()) {
    savedCity.add(oCity);
}

TinyDB tinydb = new TinyDB(this);
tinydb.putObject("city", CityArrayList.class);
```

**Here is my model**

```
public class CityArrayList {

    public ArrayList<City> cityList;

    private CityArrayList() {
        cityList = new ArrayList<City>();
    }

    public ArrayList<City> getCityList() {
        return cityList;
    }

    private static CityArrayList instance;

    public static CityArrayList getInstance() {
        if (instance == null) instance = new CityArrayList();
        return instance;
    }
}
```

**And for the city itself**

```
public class City {

    private String cityName;
    private double cityLat;
    private double cityLong;

    public City(String cityName, double cityLat, double cityLong) {
        this.cityName = cityName;
        this.cityLat = cityLat;
        this.cityLong = cityLong;
    }

    public String getCityName() {
        return cityName;
    }

    public void setCityName(String cityName) {
        this.cityName = cityName;
    }

    public double getCityLat() {
        return cityLat;
    }

    public void setCityLat(double cityLat) {
        this.cityLat = cityLat;
    }

    public double getCityLong() {
        return cityLong;
    }

    public void setCityLong(double cityLong) {
        this.cityLong = cityLong;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "City{" +
                "cityName='" + cityName + '\'' +
                ", cityLat=" + cityLat +
                ", cityLong=" + cityLong +
                '}';
    }
}
```

Comment: probably should use Realm. sharedPrefences can be cleared by user using app settings

Comment: Thank you @Shubhank , I will investigate using Realm. Sad to not have found a solution ...

Comment: `... to handle object storage into the SharedPreferences` ... which is indeed an [**anti-pattern**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anti-pattern). Let me strongly discourage you from saving and loading objects by using SharedPreferences.

Comment: Thank you for this information Bob

Comment: @BobMalooga , for my understanding, do you have any article to share with me to understand why it is an anti-pattern? Thanks a lot,

Comment: SharedPreferences should be used to store only **primitive types** key-value pairs. For searchable data, use databases. For large BLOBS, your best choice is files. https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html

Comment: Thank you @BobMalooga - much appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are passing in the wrong thing.
the `putObject` method requires you to pass in a String key and an already intantiated object, **not** a class type.

here is what your code should be to work correctly:

```
City mCity = new City(description, itemLatitude, itemLongitude);
tinydb.putObject("city", mCity);
```